# Differential Equation Inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that for all $t\in [0,1]$

$$
y' \leq 3t  + ty(t), \\
y(0) = 0.
$$

I'm asked to find the maximum possible value of $y(1)$ and to give two examples of functions $y(t)$ which satisfy this inequality.

The Hint Says that I should multiply the inequality by the integrating factor $u(t)$ one would normally use to solve this type of ODE and then to perform a definite integral.

I'm lost on what exactly I'm supposed to do here.

Comment: Mathematically, with the $\leq$ condition, I don't see that this is solvable.  You have to assume that the function $y(t$) is continuous (and probably differentiable) on the interval $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: If it helps at all, I've edited my original post to include the exact question to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid the objection raised to the previous answer, is to consider a solution $y$ defined on $[0,1]$ to the proposed question, then to define $f(t)=(3+y(t))e^{-t^2/2}$. Clearly we have 
$$f'(t)=\left(y'(t)-t(3-y(t))\right)e^{-t^2/2}\leq 0$$
So $f$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=3$ this implies that
$$
\forall\,t\in[0,1],\quad f(t)\leq 3
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
\forall\,t\in[0,1],\quad y(t)\leq 3e^{t^2/2}-3
$$
In particular, $y(1)\leq 3\sqrt{e}-3$.

Of course, $t\mapsto 0$ and $t\mapsto 3e^{t^2/2}-3$, are two solutions to the proposed inequality.

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$$
\frac{dy}{dt} \leq t\left(3 + y\right) \rightarrow \frac{dy}{3 + y} \leq tdt  \\
\ln(3 + y) \leq \frac{t^2}{2}  + C \\
y + 3 \leq Ce^{\frac{t^2}{2}}\\
y \leq -3 + Ce^{\frac{t^2}{2}}
$$

You're given that $y(0) = 0$, which would mean the following:

$$
y(0) =0=- -3 + Ce^0 =-3 + C \rightarrow C  \rightarrow C = +3\\
y(t) = -3 + 3e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}
$$

The maximum value is $y(1) = -3 + 3e^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: It seems that this approach is, in general, not correct. If, for example, it happens that 3+y<0, then you will get the different sign in the fraction. See the proof of Gronwall's inequality ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall's_inequality ) - the proof is a bit tricky, since the approach as above doesn't work.